# Is providing a "Acceptable client certificate CA names" list a security vulnerability for a server?

Tags: authentication, certificates

The certificate list I am referring to can be found using the openssl command, and is displayed under the "Acceptable client certificate CA names" heading.

I am wondering if by exposing this certificate list can be used by an attacker to become authenticated, or any other security concern.

Based on RFC 5246, 7.4.4.  Certificate Request:

> If the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType,  unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.

would it be preferable to keep the list empty and the clients will have to choose the certificate to send?

BTW, I am using mTLS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No, skipping that list just makes UX worse.

The reason for this property is so that clients can pre-select an appropriate certificate, in case that multiple certificates are installed.

For example, imagine that you have your internal ACME Certificate Authority, called `ACME Root CA`, and that has an intermediate CA for users, called `ACME Client CA`, which provisions client certificates for all employees.

You could now send `ACME Client CA` as your acceptable client CA list. That means clients will not send any client certificate signed by a different CA. If only one certificate remains, clients may auto-select that one, making it very easy for users.

#### But isn't that a huge vulnerability?!

No, it's not. Imagine I am an attacker and see that only certificates by `ACME Client CA` are allowed - so I create a certificate authority called `ACME Client CA` and sign my own certificate with it.

And indeed, a browser *would* consider this certificate valid and would present it to the server. But the server would reject it, because the signature of my own "fake" `ACME Client CA` would not match the public key of the certificate, which the server expects.

So by giving the attacker the name `ACME Client CA`, you don't give them any information that would make an attack easier. Therefore, populating the acceptable CA list is a recommended thing to do, if possible. It will not make your security worse.

#### How does this make UX worse?

Imagine your users have several client certificates installed, up to 10. Whenever they wish to authenticate with your system, they now have to look through that list and select the correct one for your system. This is time-consuming, error-prone and requires users to be taught which item is the correct one.

All of this could be avoided by just pre-configuring which certificate is expected by your application.

Comment: In what part it makes UX worse?

Comment: @Crypt32 I edited the answer to clarify. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but I would disagree with this statement. pre-configuring the certificate adds maintenance overhead since you have to update bindings every time client certificate is changed and tends to failure in long-term run in a large scale.

Comment: @Crypt32 No, you don't. You don't identify the client certificates per se, you identify the CA that signed them - or more precisely, the name of that CA. If your old CA expires and your new CA gets provisioned, giving it the same name is all you have to do.

Comment: @SergeBallesta That comment makes no sense. Detecting whether employees install certificates on their machines is a *wholly* different mechanism than the Acceptable Client Certificate List